# For $x_n\to x$, is there homeomorphisms $f_n$ with $d(f_n(x_n), f_n(x))>\epsilon$ ? ($\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Is there a sequence of homeomorphisms $f_n:X\to X$ such that $d(f_n(x_n), f_n(x))>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$? (for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: Obviously false if $x_n=x$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Take $X=\bigcup_{n \geq 0}{S^n}$ where the union is disjoint and $S^0$ is a singleton $\{x^0\}$.

The distance between any $x,y \in S^n$ when $n \geq 1$ is $\frac{1}{10n^3}\frac{1}{1+|x-y|_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}}$. The distance between $x \in S^n$, $y \in S^m$, $m > n > 0$, is $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}$, and the distance between $x \in S^n$ and $x^0$ is $1/n$.

Take for every $n \geq 1$ $x_n \in S^n$. Then $x_n$ converges to $x^0$, and, for every homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ into itself, $f(x_n) \in S^n$ so is at distance $1/n$ from $x^0$.

Comment: Thanks. In my research, I obtain a sequence homeomorphisms $f_n:X\to X$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $d(f_n(x_n), f_n(x))>\epsilon$. Can I say that it is a contradiction?($X$ is a compact metric space)

Comment: As is, no. Maybe though you can have some more information about $X$, the $f_n$’s qnd the $x_n$’s?

Comment: In my research, there is a sequence $\{g_k:X\to X\}$, such that $d_0(g_k, f)<\frac{1}{k}$ and for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n(k)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(g^{n(k)}_k(x_k), g^{n(k)}_k(x))>\epsilon$. Note that $x_k\to x$ as $k\to \infty$, $d_0(g, f)= \sup_{x\in X} d(f(x), g(x))$ and $f^n=f\circ f\circ\ldots \circ f$ ($n$- times).